# unittest пропуск тестов по условию

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, selenium-webdriver

Есть класс с тестами. Я задаю глобальную переменную `is_work = True` которая означает что сайт работает. Затем вызывается функция `setUpClass` где я открываю страницу сайта. Если возникает ошибка в вебдрайвере я меняю значение `is_work` на False.

Затем должен запуститься тест `test_my`, перед этим проверив декоратором нужно ли пропустить тест. И проблема в том, что `is_work = True` всегда. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся.

```
class unctionalTests(unittest.TestCase):
    is_work = True

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """Set up for class"""
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        try:
            cls.driver.get(url)
        except WebDriverException:
            is_work = False


    @unittest.skipIf(is_work == False,"Site {} not work".format(site))
    def test_my(self):
        ....
```

Answer (score 1):

К полям класса обращайтесь через `cls` (это ссылка на сам класс, передаваемая в методы класса, аналогично экземпляру объекта `self` для обычных методов):

```
class unctionalTests(unittest.TestCase):
    is_work = True

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """Set up for class"""
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        try:
            cls.driver.get(url)
        except WebDriverException:
            cls.is_work = False
```

Проверка в декораторе должна выглядеть так:

```
@unittest.skipIf(unctionalTests.is_work == False,"Site {} not work".format(site))
def test_my(self):
    ....
```

Демонстрационный пример:

```
class A:
    test = True

    @classmethod
    def make_false(cls):
        cls.test = False


print(A.test)  # выведет True
A.make_false()
print(A.test)  # выведет False
```

### Обновлено:

Для пропуска тестов вместо декораторов можно явно вызывать [`skipTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.skipTest) внутри `setUp` или тестового метода:

```
class unctionalTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """Set up for class"""
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        try:
            cls.driver.get(url)
        except WebDriverException:
            cls.skipTest("Site {} not work".format(site))
```

Comment: То что вы пишете, правильно. Но проблема в другом. Декоратор в момент вызова декорируемой функции не видит изменения переменной. Скорее всего переменная `is_work` проверяется в момент инициализации класса

Comment: Тогда мне кажется проще обойтись без декоратора, а прямо в сетапе вызывать [skipTest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.skipTest), если соединение не успешно.